# read OWL 2 Axiom in plain english

Tags: owl, ontology

I am trying to understand the following axioms of OWL 2 but don't know what kind of axioms they are. here R is role and C is class

1. ∃R ⊑ C
2. ∃R ⊑ ∃R.C
3. C ⊑ ¬∃R
4. ∃R ⊑ ¬C

As far i think 1 gives information about Range of R,but i am not sure. Thanks

Comment: Hrm, maybe 1 should be `∃R.⊤ ⊑ C`  (domain axiom)?

Comment: hm, so this is description logic syntax. all of those are basically subclass axioms indicated by `⊑` symbol.. It also looks like for brevity, the top (equivalent to `owl:Thing` in OWL) symbol `⊤` has been omitted. maybe you can have a look at description logics and OWL?. Otherwise, 1, 2 and 3 are domain axioms for property `R` with the domain being on the right side of the `⊑` symbol

Comment: 2 is a range axiom - it assigns a type to the individual in object position of an R property assertion.

Comment: This freely available paper has examples that are very similar to the ones in the question: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.4089.pdf A Description Logic Primer by Markus Krötzsch, František Simancík, Ian Horrocks

Comment: @StanislavKralin yes 1 is domain axiom as explained below.

Comment: @Ignazio Thankyou for the reference material. it helps alot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to make sense of these axioms is to understand the semantics of the Description Logic constructors used:

`∃R` is the short form of `∃R.T` (where `T` refers to the top concept which represents the complete domain). Mathematically

`(∃R.T)^I = {x ∈ δ^I | A y exists such that (x, y) ∈ R^I and y ∈ T^I}`

This states that ∃R.T represents the set of individuals consisting of `x` such that `x` is associated via relation `R` to at least 1 individual `y` that is in top (the domain of discourse). If we had ∃R.C rather than `T`, `y` will be in `C`.

`C ⊑ D` states that all individuals of type `C` are also of type `D`. That is `C` is a subset of `D`.

`∃R ⊑ C` means all the individuals linked to at least 1 individual via relation `R` is a subset of `C`. That is why `∃R ⊑ C` is also known as a domain axiom because it enforces that for all relations `(x, y)` in `R`, that `x` will be of type `C`.

`¬C` defines all the individuals that are not of type `C` in the domain of interpretation.

Going through the rest of these axioms in a similar way will help you to understand their meaning.